# Парсинг динамически изменяющейся веб-страницы

Tags: c++, вконтакте

Хочется вытащить названия и имена исполнителей музыки из печально известного (отрубившего метод API audio.get) вконтакта.

В принципе, используя свои куки, я могу забрать исходный код своей страницы с аудио и после этого распарсить композиции. Но проблема в том, что контент там подгружается динамически, то есть - промотал до низа список аудио - подгрузилась еще кучка, и так далее.

Вопрос в том, как эмулировать это "проматывание". Писать все это дело хотелось бы на C++, посему хотелось бы получить советы насчет библиотек, которые мне могут помочь в данной задаче (ранее имел дело с libcurl, но не уверен, что это лучший вариант).

Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите запрос к серверу, который возникает когда страница начинает подгружать контент.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать selenium с каким-нибудь браузером. Например, даже PhantomJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я посмотрел, как устроены аудиозаписи вк. Оказывается, контент там подгружается не динамически. Он загружается весь, сразу после загрузки страницы по Ajax запросу. Если вы перейдете в своем браузере в режим разработчика (как правило F12), далее во вкладку Network(Сеть), после чего откроете страницу аудиозапесей, то увидите, как появилось несколько запросов. Один из них - POST запрос к al_audio.php - это то, что вам нужно!

Возможно потребуется симулировать поведение пользователя - определяйте опытным путем. Если потребуется, то это очень просто сделать библиотекой requests в Python. Есть ли что-то похожее в плюсах, к сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: Благодарю! Сначала тоже смотрел запросы через консоль разработчика, но как-то прошел мимо поста к al_audio.php.